# Read the GIS data with "Interrupted Goode's Homolosine Projection Binary Format" using R

Tags: r, gis, binaryfiles, spatial

I am trying to load the GIS data with "Interrupted Goode's Homolosine Projection Binary Format" into R, but I don't know how to do it.

The data example can get from the following linkage:
ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/Continuous_Fields_Tree_Cover/Global/gl-goodes-treecover/gl-goodes-deciduous.bin.gz

I tried to use the function "read.ENVI" in the R package "caTools", but it doesn't work.

```
> library(caTools)
Loading required package: bitops
> r <- read.ENVI("gl-goodes-deciduous")
Error in read.ENVI("gl-goodes-deciduous") : 
  read.ENVI: Could not open input header file: gl-goodes-deciduous.hdr
```

Any suggestions? Thanks~

Comment: I cannot see why you would expect this to work, that file is just raw binary. Presumably somewhere there are instructions on the layout of the file, and/or extra metadata that format drivers could understand. The file here gives some clues, possibly: ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/Continuous_Fields_Tree_Cover/Global/AVHRR_DECIDUOUS_1992_1993/AVHRR_DECIDUOUS_1992_1993.GLOBAL.met

Comment: There's a .glcf file in the same folder as the .bin.gz file with the required metadata. Although number of lines * pixels per line in that file comes up 163 bytes shorter than the gunzipped file size, which makes me think the .bin does have some kind of header...

Comment: I get values in [0,80] with this, not bored enough to do the rest. :)  d <- readBin("gl0101bs", "integer", size = 1, n = 17347 * 40031)

Comment: Jian Zhang see here for a similar problem with a couple of approaches, you also need the projection if you are going to add other map data to this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14848/problems-with-na-values-when-reading-dem-file-with-r-raster-package-in-window and spatialreference.org should have the right PROJ.4 for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a machine that can read the whole 600M+ binary file in without choking then great. Otherwise you might want to make use of the raster package's skill at using GDAL imagery on disk.

First create a file called `gl-goodes-deciduous.vrt` that looks like this:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="40031" rasterYSize="17347">
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1" subClass="VRTRawRasterBand">
    <SourceFilename relativetoVRT="1">gl-goodes-deciduous.bin</SourceFilename>
    <ImageOffset>0</ImageOffset>
    <PixelOffset>1</PixelOffset>
    <LineOffset>40031</LineOffset>
    <ByteOrder>MSB</ByteOrder>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

This gives the GDAL library enough info to read the data. You might also want to read the docs on VRTs to get the coordinates right. Then in R, open the VRT and plot a low-res sample of it:

```
> require(raster)
> r = raster("gl-goodes-deciduous.vrt")
> plot(r,maxpixels=100*100)
```

ProTip: Whenever there's a .tif file available, use that, since it might be a GeoTIFF with all the required metadata built in.

I am slightly worried that Nrows times Ncolumns is 163 bytes shorter than the file, but maybe there's a footer, or maybe ImageOffset should be 163 to offset this.

Comment: +1! just one question in the xml header, how did you set the rasterXSize="40031" rasterYSize="17347"?

Comment: That's what it says in the file in the FTP site folder: ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/Continuous_Fields_Tree_Cover/Global/gl-goodes-treecover/gl-goodes-treecover.glcf in the section for gl-goodes-deciduous (seems to be the same for all the imagery)